# Mysql...Impossible query?

Tags: mysql

Difficult query. Not sure if this is possible.

I am trying to figure out how to format a query that needs to accomplish several things.

(1) I need to parse the DATE field that is a VARCHAR field and not a sql date field to get the month of each date.

(2) I then need to AVG all the PTS fields by NAME and Month. So with my example data below I would have a row that has John and John would have 2 in the JAN column and 3 in the the APR column and the AVG column would be an average of all the months. So the months are an average of all the entries in that month and the AVG column is an average of all the columns in the row.

Table:

```
Name (VARCAHR)  PTS (INT) DATE (VARCHAR)        
---------------------------------------------
John            3           Tue Apr 14 17:56:02 2020
Chris           2           Tue Apr 14 19:44:03 2020
John            2           Mon Jan 30 15:23:03 2020
Chris           4           Fri Feb 28 16:15:15 2020
John            3           Tue Apr 14 17:56:02 2020


Table Layout on web page:
Name        Jan     Feb     Mar     Apr     May     Jun     Jul     Aug     Sep     Oct     Nov     Dec     Average
```

Comment: very poor choice of date storage purpose... Store as a full date/time / timestamp, whatever field, not varchar.  Then you can always query the components such as month( dateField), year( dateField ), etc... Parsing will only give you headaches and poor query performance if ever trying to query by that column for range of activity.

Comment: I am working on getting the data fixed. Currently i am importing the data from a csv in phpmyadmin and the date wont import into a date time field. Eventually I want to have a script to import the data manually and then I can probably figure a way to get it into the datetime field...maybe I should have started there.

Comment: @XenPanda you can do data processing on import to convert those values into datetime format (using `STR_TO_DATE` as I did in my answer). See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html#load-data-input-preprocessing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not impossible, just convoluted. You can use [`STR_TO_DATE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) to convert your strings into `DATETIME` objects, from which you can then use [`MONTH`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_month) to get the month number. Note though (as @DRapp commented) that you should be storing `DATETIME` values in their native form, not as `VARCHAR`, then you wouldn't have to deal with `STR_TO_DATE`. Having got the month number, you can then use conditional aggregation to get the results you want:

```
SELECT name,
       COALESCE(AVG(CASE WHEN mth = 1 THEN PTS END), 0) AS Jan,
       COALESCE(AVG(CASE WHEN mth = 2 THEN PTS END), 0) AS Feb,
       COALESCE(AVG(CASE WHEN mth = 3 THEN PTS END), 0) AS Mar,
       COALESCE(AVG(CASE WHEN mth = 4 THEN PTS END), 0) AS Apr,
       -- repeat for May to November
       COALESCE(AVG(CASE WHEN mth = 12 THEN PTS END), 0) AS `Dec`,
       AVG(PTS) AS AVG
FROM (
  SELECT name, PTS AS PTS, MONTH(STR_TO_DATE(DATE, '%a %b %e %H:%i:%s %Y')) AS mth
  FROM data
) d
GROUP BY name
```

Output (for your sample data):

```
name    Jan     Feb     Mar     Apr     Dec     AVG
Chris   0       4       0       2       0       3
John    0       0       0       2.6667  0       2.6667
```

[Demo on SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/da19665/9)

Comment: Thanks for this. I will have a look and try this out in a bit. I appreciate you answering my question.

Comment: Code looks great. It is above my level so I am having trouble integrating into my webpage, but I cannot post the code here so I am going to have to ask for the fix in another question. Based on the information provided I believe you have answered the original question. Thanks!

Comment: @XenPanda no worries. I'll look out for your new question, perhaps I can help with that too.

Comment: Thanks. If you get a chance this is the link to it. [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61264236/cant-figure-how-to-get-data-from-mysql-query] new question