# Can't figure how to get data from MySql Query

Tags: php, html, mysql

I asked a question earlier on how to do this query and received a great response. Unfortunately it is a bit more advanced than the queries I normally run so I cannot figure out how to retrieve the results and display them on my web page. Here is the link to the original question [original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61263200/mysql-impossible-query/61263336?noredirect=1#comment108379978_61263336)

```
     <?php

// Associative array
$result = $db->query("SELECT Name,
       COALESCE(AVG(CASE WHEN mth = 1 THEN PTS END), 0) AS Jan,
       COALESCE(AVG(CASE WHEN mth = 2 THEN PTS END), 0) AS Feb,
       COALESCE(AVG(CASE WHEN mth = 3 THEN PTS END), 0) AS Mar,
       COALESCE(AVG(CASE WHEN mth = 4 THEN PTS END), 0) AS Apr,
       COALESCE(AVG(CASE WHEN mth = 5 THEN PTS END), 0) AS May,
       COALESCE(AVG(CASE WHEN mth = 6 THEN PTS END), 0) AS Jun,
       COALESCE(AVG(CASE WHEN mth = 7 THEN PTS END), 0) AS Jul,
       COALESCE(AVG(CASE WHEN mth = 8 THEN PTS END), 0) AS Aug,
       COALESCE(AVG(CASE WHEN mth = 9 THEN PTS END), 0) AS Sep,
       COALESCE(AVG(CASE WHEN mth = 10 THEN PTS END), 0) AS Oct,
       COALESCE(AVG(CASE WHEN mth = 11 THEN PTS END), 0) AS Nov,
       COALESCE(AVG(CASE WHEN mth = 12 THEN PTS END), 0) AS Dec,
       AVG(PTS) AS AVG
FROM (
  SELECT Name, `Points Pass` AS PTS, MONTH(STR_TO_DATE(`OS Date`, '%a %b %e %H:%i:%s %Y')) AS mth
  FROM data
) d
GROUP BY Name");


while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

            ?>

         <tr>
                <td><?php echo $row['Name']; ?></td>
                <td class = "gScore-<?php echo $row['Jan']; ?>"><?php echo $row['Jan']; ?></td>
                <td class = "gScore-<?php echo $row['Feb']; ?>"><?php echo $row['Feb']; ?></td>
                <td class = "gScore-<?php echo $row['Mar']; ?>"><?php echo $row['Mar']; ?></td>
                <td class = "gScore-<?php echo $row['Apr']; ?>"><?php echo $row['Apr']; ?></td>
                <td class = "gScore-<?php echo $row['May']; ?>"><?php echo $row['May']; ?></td>
                <td class = "gScore-<?php echo $row['Jun']; ?>"><?php echo $row['Jun']; ?></td>
                <td class = "gScore-<?php echo $row['Jul']; ?>"><?php echo $row['Jul']; ?></td>
                <td class = "gScore-<?php echo $row['Aug']; ?>"><?php echo $row['Aug']; ?></td>
                <td class = "gScore-<?php echo $row['Sep']; ?>"><?php echo $row['Sep']; ?></td>
                <td class = "gScore-<?php echo $row['Oct']; ?>"><?php echo $row['Oct']; ?></td>
                <td class = "gScore-<?php echo $row['Nov']; ?>"><?php echo $row['Nov']; ?></td>
                <td class = "gScore-<?php echo $row['Dec']; ?>"><?php echo $row['Dec']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['AVG']; ?></td>
            </tr>
        <?php   


}
if (!$result) { echo $db->error; }
```

Comment: Error message received: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, bool given in

Comment: That means you had an error in your query - you need to add `if (!$result) { echo $db->error; }` to your code to find out what it was

Comment: I cleaned up the code and edited the original post. I changed a couple of fields to match my actual db. The part you didnt know what I was doing was to use the result to style the output based on the result with css classes. I put in the code you suggested for the error message and this is what I got `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'AS PTS, MONTH(STR_TO_DATE(OS Date, '%a %b %e %H:%i:%s %Y')) AS mth FROM data ' at line 16`

Comment: Seems like it is related to one of the fields I changed. I have tried it 2 ways and the same error. I tried like the code above and then I tried it changing the second Points Pass to PTS like the original code you provided.

Comment: If your column name is actually `Points Pass` you need to enclose it in backticks i.e. `SELECT Name, \`Points Pass\` AS PTS, ...`

Comment: It's important that you have the `AS PTS` in the subquery so that the upper level query works properly.

Comment: I changed more things in the original code to better match my db. Thats the last time I don't use the actual db field names in a question. Anyway still getting and error. `Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, bool given in filename-removed
Table 'traps.data' doesn't exist` weird thing is the db connection stuff worked fine before and the db is traps not the table. The table is grades.

Comment: Oh i see. it means db traps.table and the query has data as the table.

Comment: I called my table `data` for the answer to your previous question because I didn't know what yours was called. Just replace `data` in the subquery with `grades`

Comment: I understand...I just didn't notice it.

Comment: Ok. It works now. Thank you so much!

Comment: No worries - I'm glad we managed to get it sorted.

Comment: Note that you will run into issues with your classes as the average numbers can be floating point. You might want to convert them into ranges before trying to use them as a class name

Comment: I plan to run them through a rounding function, thats why my original code didnt have the $row['field'] format when I first posted. Now that I have the data I should't have an issue doing that again.

Comment: Gotcha. That makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few issues:

1. The indexes to `$row` need to be enclosed in quotes e.g. `$row['name']` otherwise you will get a lot of "Undefined constant" warnings;
2. `$row['Jan']` is the correct way to retrieve the monthly data, you need to replicate that for each of the other months;
3. replace `$avgGrade` with `$row['AVG']`
4. I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve with

```
<td class = "gScore-<?php echo $row[Jan]; ?>"></td>
```

do you actually want

```
<td class = "gScore"><?php echo $row[Jan]; ?></td>
```

5. you need to add the `-- repeat for May to November` rows to the query i.e.

```
    $result = $db->query("SELECT name,
       COALESCE(AVG(CASE WHEN mth = 1 THEN PTS END), 0) AS Jan,
       COALESCE(AVG(CASE WHEN mth = 2 THEN PTS END), 0) AS Feb,
       COALESCE(AVG(CASE WHEN mth = 3 THEN PTS END), 0) AS Mar,
       COALESCE(AVG(CASE WHEN mth = 4 THEN PTS END), 0) AS Apr,
       COALESCE(AVG(CASE WHEN mth = 5 THEN PTS END), 0) AS May,
       COALESCE(AVG(CASE WHEN mth = 6 THEN PTS END), 0) AS Jun,
       COALESCE(AVG(CASE WHEN mth = 7 THEN PTS END), 0) AS Jul,
       COALESCE(AVG(CASE WHEN mth = 8 THEN PTS END), 0) AS Aug,
       COALESCE(AVG(CASE WHEN mth = 9 THEN PTS END), 0) AS Sep,
       COALESCE(AVG(CASE WHEN mth = 10 THEN PTS END), 0) AS Oct,
       COALESCE(AVG(CASE WHEN mth = 11 THEN PTS END), 0) AS Nov,
       COALESCE(AVG(CASE WHEN mth = 12 THEN PTS END), 0) AS `Dec`,
       AVG(PTS) AS AVG
   FROM (
   SELECT name, PTS AS PTS, MONTH(STR_TO_DATE(DATE, '%a %b %e %H:%i:%s %Y')) AS mth
   FROM data
    ) d
    GROUP BY name");
```

Comment: My bad, I will make some changes. I had not fixed a bunch of the old variables in the code because I didn't even know how to iterate the result and figured it wasn't even getting that far.

Comment: @XenPanda give them a try, and also put in the error checking code as I suggested in my comment under your question, and then let me know what you get.